# the difference between makecform('srgb2xyz') and rgb2xyz() in matlab

Tags: matlab, color-space

I wonder what the matlab does when using the function rgb2xyz()? 
I cannot re-produce the results using the rgb2xyz conversion matrix.. 
Moreover, is there any difference between using makecform('srgb2xyz') and using rgb2xyz()? they produce difference results..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default white point for `makecform('srgb2xyz')` appears to  be `D50`, whereas `rgb2xyz` defaults to `D65`.

```
>> applycform([.2 .3 .4],makecform('srgb2xyz','AdaptedWhitePoint',whitepoint('D65')))

ans =

0.0638    0.0690    0.1356

>> rgb2xyz([.2 .3 .4])

ans =

0.0638    0.0690    0.1356

>> applycform([.2 .3 .4],makecform('srgb2xyz'))

ans =

0.0617    0.0679    0.1024

>> rgb2xyz([.2 .3 .4],'WhitePoint','D50')

ans =

0.0616    0.0679    0.1025
```

Note the documentation for `makecform` suggests using the more recent `rgb2xyz` instead.  As for your comment about reproducing the results using a matrix, note that the matrices are generally derived from / applied to *linear* data.  If you want to reproduce the results you'll need to model the srgb gamma correction as well.

Comment: But is there any preference for choosing the D65 or D50?? I'm doing a segmentation work and somehow using command 'rgb2xyz' gives me a much better result..

Comment: Unless you know your your input images are encoded in some other color space, D65 is a good guess. Most images on the web are encoded assuming an sRGB display and sRGB is reasonable description of most common monitors.  sRGB defines the white point as D65.  By the way if you find my answer useful please mark as accepted.